# Need a simple text editor inside angular application with simple text output

Tags: angular, text, text-editor

I need a simple text editor inside my angular application which should have the line number and column number indication and output a simple text(non WSYIWYG). Example, like a notepad++ main window. Mostly all available packages are WYSIWYG type which produces html as a output, I need a simple text output
Is there any package available for the same.

Comment: Heard of VS Code?

Comment: Sorry for misleading.. rephrased my question

Answer (score 2):

1. For Code Editor - [@ngstack/code-editor](https://github.com/ngstack/code-editor)
2. Normal Text Editor - [ngx-quill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-quill)

Comment: i do not need a code editor but need a simple text editor which outputs plain text with line number and column number indication. Incase of ngx-quill it is a rich text editor(WYSIWYG based) gives a html output. I don't need that

Comment: the code editor kind of serves my requirement but when I include angular mentions to it, it is not working properly. Do you know any ways/work around for this